# Regex + artificial intelligence

Tags: regex, artificial-intelligence

How would it be possible to write software that takes strings from a list and generates regular expressions based on a pattern in each line of the list.

Comment: Can you give an example of your list and your patterns/expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regular expressions are regular, it means they are used to match well defined patterns. If you need a kind of fuzzy matching, regular expressions are not needed or valid for that. If you need a "find similar text" algorithm, forget about regular expressions and use one of machine learning algorithms. Google "machine learning algorithms".

BTW, it's not too hard to make a program which would generate regular expressions matching a set of strings, but it would make sense if made only for fun or learning purposes, I can't imagine what else could it be useful for.

You could for example get an expression matching if something "looks like e-mail address", but you couldn't really tell if it's an e-mail address indeed, because to determine that you would need a strict set of rules applied, rules that could not be automatically determined from any sample of real-world e-mail addresses significantly smaller than the actual number of all existing e-mail accounts.

If I would do something like that for fun, I would first "extract" the rule of the length. No shorter than the shortest, no longer than the longest. Then character set limited to only existing in the set, or extended to full alphanumeric. No extending on special characters. It would probably work for some cases, fail miserably for others.